# Display iPad screen as iPhone?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have searched through the web and I did not get clues.
Is there a way to display iPad screen as an iPhone like this app does it?

[image]

The iPad displays an iPhone screen. Is there some configuration to display this behavior?

Comment: I know is a bad practice to force this, but I want it as a workaround..

Comment: Set your app supported devices to iPhone instead of Universal

Comment: I'm not seeing it. The image appears to be an iPhone *only* app that - by Apple's rules - is being displayed in an iPad. To do this on an iPhone? It's possible, but (1) consider the "black space" surrounding everything - on an iPhone X (XS, XS max) **much less** a 4 inch iPhone SE? Nobody wants that. I really think you have things backwards! Now if you wish for separate Storyboards for iPhone/iPad, or maybe some code in AppDelegate to pass what device you are rendering... sure. But no app available for a 4 inch screen decides to display it's UI in 2 inches of space.

Comment: @dfd he’s asking about iPad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the default behavior of running an iPhone-only app on an iPad. You don't have to do anything other than declare your iOS app as an iPhone-only app.

Of course it would be better for your users if your app properly worked on and took advantage of the iPad's screen but that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If the supported devices, that appear under Project > Target > General Tab > Deployment Info [image]

is selected to be "iPhone" and you run this version of app on an iPad, it will appear as the example you shared.